# Using reverse relations in django class based views

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a django model as follows:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Product"
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.model_name
```

In my views, i have a ListView as follows:

```
class CategoryList(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'categories.html'
```

And my categories.html is as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h2>Categories</h2>

        {% for category in object_list %}
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="h{{category.id}}">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{category.id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{category.id}}">
                          {{category.category_name}}
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="{{category.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="h{{category.id}}">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{category.category_name}} //trying to change here by displaying all model_names!!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now I am trying to show a list of all the products available in a category inside the accordion in the template (i.e in the panel-body). How do I change the view to access these reverse relations? Am fairly new to class based views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the related products for each category using the related field manager `products_set`, eg:

```
{{category.category_name}} //trying to change here by displaying all model_names!!
<ul>
{% for product in category.product_set.all %}
  <li>{{ product.model_name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you need more complicated filtering, you'd want to either do that in your view or write a custom template tag. Doing it in the view would look something like this:

```
class CategoryList(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'categories.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(CategoryList, self).get_queryset()
        for category in qs:
            category.some_filtered_products = category.product_set.filter(...)
        return qs
```

That will resolve the queryset during the view and put the filtered products into a new in-memory attribute on each `Category` instance.

Comment: wow!! didnt know we could use it directly in the template! Thank you

Comment: Yep - you can't pass arguments to methods in the template, but anything that can be evaluated using no arguments works fine. See the "behind the scenes" box here for some details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#variables