# How To Use Reverse Relations in Django Class Based Views - 2

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I'm creating a to-do list where I want the tasks to get displayed on its respective date, but I'm having a hard time doing so.

I found another resource that kind of answered a similar question, but I'm still having a hard time implementing the query with reverse relations, and not quite sure how to put it on template.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818449/using-reverse-relations-in-django-class-based-views)

Been spending 2 or 3 days stuck on this. Hope I could get some pointers here

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkEMM.jpg)

[Current Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flIyt.jpg)

My models:

```
class Dailies(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    the_user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

class DailyTask(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dailies = models.ForeignKey(
        Dailies,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

My ListView:

```
class DailiesListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Dailies

    template_name = 'home.html'

    context_object_name = 'date'

    ordering = ['-date']

    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['date'] = context['date'].filter(the_user=self.request.user)
        context['todos'] = DailyTask.objects.filter(
            dailies__the_user=self.request.user)

        return context
```

My template (home.html):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    
    {% for each_date in date %}
    <h3>
        <li>
            {{each_date}}: 
            {% for todo in todos %} 
                {{todo}}
            {% endfor %}
        </li>  
    </h3>   
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using {% for todo in each_date.dailytask_set.all %}, it allowed me to iterate correctly.

What I did is that I used RelatedManager by using "_set", and it allowed me to trace back to dailytask and iterate out the tasks that corresponds to their dates. And that gave me the desired outcome.

Thankyou *@mirodil* for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

In your template `{% for todo in date.dailies_set.all %}` you're getting dailies from date which always retrieve all dates, but you should try to get it from `each_date`, so your code should be like that.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    
    {% for each_date in date %}
    <h3>
        <li>
            {{each_date}}: 
            {% for todo in each_date.dailies_set.all %}
                <br>
                {{todo}}
            {% endfor %}
        </li>  
    </h3>   
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: sorry, my original posted code wasn't correct, it was actually {% for todo in todos%}

Comment: You've already gotten date related to `request.user` and you need to get todos related to that `date`

Comment: My question would be, how would I reverse query back from date(from Dailies model) to DailyTask model in order to get all the tasks per date?

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: Yes, it only printed out the dates, and not the tasks corresponding to their dates.

Comment: try this to get tasks  `{{todo.task}}`